# slideshow won't scale width on mobile

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, responsive-design

I have a slideshow on my homepage that scales to 100% width. It works perfectly on my computer (I can even resize my browser windows all the way down, in both Firefox and Safari, and it works great) but it doesn't work on my iphone (it stays too wide and adds a lot of blank space to the right of the page content).

The slideshow is an iframe. I've tried scaling the iframe with html, putting it in a div and scaling the div with css, and I've tried this: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/, but nothing seems to be working. Does anyone have any ideas I can try?

Thanks!!

website: www.silvervinedesign.com

Comment: Just emulated your site on Iphone 3 -6, looks fine.

Comment: If you scroll down past the slideshow and then scroll right, you should run into a lot of empty white space because the slideshow is too long. The rest of the page is responsive so it looks ok if you scroll straight down, but the slideshow isn't scaling its width...

Comment: I'm still not seeing it, but I am using an emulation so its not exact.  If the slideshow is too long, but the images seem to scale, couldn't you just set the overflow to hidden?

Comment: Kind of. It does solve the white space problem, but it also cuts off the last one or two photos and the right arrow button and half of the little slider button underneath, because they're stuck in the hidden part. I was hoping there was a better fix than that, but if that's as good as it gets then I'll just have to get used to it :)

Comment: Try clearing your cache for that site.  If in chrome, go to settings -> advanced -> content settings -> all cookies & site data -> type in your site and clear the cookies.  Last idea I have for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have pixel widths defined for the styles of this element. Therefore, it won't be responsive.

If you inspect the source of this iframe (right click and choose "Inspect Element"), you'll find that the `<ul>` element containing the images is getting a `style="width: 4778px;"` applied to it. Each `<li>` child is also getting an explicit pixel width style applied. When I view the source of the `iframe`, these `style` tags are not present there.

That tells me you've got some javascript function which is setting this width. Looking at your source, I'm guessing the plugin responsible is `galleria`, but it's hard to tell.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense- I think galleria is what scales the photography pages (like [link](http://silvervinedesign.com/gallery/kayla-ben)), and the iframe on the homepage is just the slideshow cut out of one of those pages. So I can't get rid of it without messing up the other galleries... Can/ should I disable the js in just that div somehow? Or disable all horizontal scrolling on mobile? How come it works on the computer but not on the phone?

Comment: I wish I knew javascript, but I _think_ this is the line that determines the slideshow width? 

function getContainerWidth(){
    var maxWidth = jQuery('.level-one').data('max-length')*300;
    return maxWidth;
}

I can keep looking if that doesn't help :S

Comment: I don't think that's the right line. Changing the height of the window alters the `width` value of the `<ul>`. Rather than hack someone else's plugin, I'd look at using a different plugin for the slideshow on the homepage and get rid of the `iframe` all together.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll just deal with it being cut off for now, but I'll keep looking for a better plugin too. Surprisingly I haven't been able to find any decent slideshow plugins that scroll horizontally and allow both vertical & horizontal photos; I actually looked for about a week before I gave up & resorted to the iframe. But thank you very much for all your help!!